# NSArray writeToFile returning "is deprecated" - iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I'm trying to save some settings from my app to a plist file when it closes, then load them when the app launches. I have 4 numbers saved in an NSArray called array. The loading works fine because if I change the file, the app starts the way the file was changed.

This code works fine:

```
- (void)LoadSettings {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:kSaveFileLocation];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
clockFaceImageSlider.value = [[array objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
HourTypeSwitch.on = [[array objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
touchRotationSwitch.on = [[array objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];
accelerometerRotationSwitch.on = [[array objectAtIndex:3] integerValue];
}
```

This code works up to the save line:

```
- (void)SaveSettings {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:kSaveFileLocation];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:clockFaceImageSlider.value], [NSNumber numberWithInt:HourTypeSwitch.on], [NSNumber numberWithInt:touchRotationSwitch.on], [NSNumber numberWithInt:accelerometerRotationSwitch.on], nil];

    if (![array writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
    //The log does print error
}
```

Does anybody know how I can make it save to the plist?

~thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of taking the `description` (which is an `NSString`) of an `NSArray` and write it to a file, just use `writeToFile:atomically` of `NSArray` itself, as in

```
[array writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

The reason `writeToFile:atomically:` of an `NSString` is deprecated is that it doesn't correctly account for the character encodings.  Who told you to use `description`? That person/book should be punished...

That said, if you want to save just a few entries, it would be easier to just use `NSUserDefaults`, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i). Then all you have to do is

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: ... forKey:@"..."]
```

and the framework does everything from preparing a plist path behind the scenes to saving it to the disk.

Answer (score 4):

Dont write array's description NSString, just write the array instead:

```
[array writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

Or if you want the strings you should use en encoding type

```
NSError *error;
[[array description] writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncodingerror:&error];
```

but this will not write a plist.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am no longer getting an error, but it is not saving. I modified my code to check is it saved, and it's returning the error message. I've updated my question.

Comment: You have to write your files in Documents directory of you app. That is the only place you have permission.
NSString *documentsDirectory =
                [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]; is the folder you want to save your stuff.